# How do I create a ZIP archive that preserves only the structure of the target directory and below?

Tags: command-line, directory, cd-command, zip

I need to create a zip archive where the unzipped result preserves the directory structure *from* the specified directory down.  I also need to do this *without* actually switching to the directory.

My question is *similar* to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710141/create-). After having read a great deal on the issue, I don't feel that anything has completely answered my question.

For example, I have:

```
/tmp
    /sub_dir
        /pertinent_dir
            /sub_folder_1/
                stuff.pdf
                stuff.xls
            /sub_folder_2/
                stuff.pdf
                stuff.xls
            /sub_folder_3/
                stuff.pdf
                stuff.xls
```

I need to be able to perform `zip -r /tmp/sub_dir/pertinent_dir.zip  /tmp/sub_dir/pertinent_dir/*` such that the result only contains `pertinent_dir` and below.  Again, I need to do this *regardless* of my current directory context.  I've tried `-j`, but that doesn't seem to work.  Perhaps it's not possible.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you opposed to changing to the target directory within a subshell and doing the zip within that same subshell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sh -c "cd /tmp/sub_dir/pertinent_dir/../  \
&& zip -r pertinent_dir.zip pertinent_dir/*"
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use jar instead of zip:

```
jar cfM /tmp/sub_dir/pertinent_dir.zip -C /tmp/sub_dir pertinent_dir
```

Comment: You should probably mention that `jar` is part of the Java installation, and creates compatible zipfiles which can be extracted with unzip and so on.